# I am creating code that creates a song list and not sure why I am getting a TypeError:

Tags: list, dictionary, typeerror

I'm trying to create a python code that allows a user to input a song and a artist and then to print out the song title by artist

Here is the code that I created

```
playlist=[]

def song_info(song, artist = "Unknown"):
    selection = ({"song_title": song , "song_artist": artist})

    playlist.append(selection)

def song_list(playlist):    
    for song in playlist:
        if song['song_title'] == True:
            print(playlist['song_title'] + 'by' + playlist,['song_artist'])


answer ='Y'
while answer != 'n':
    artist= input('Please input the name of the song: ')
    song = input (" Please input the name of the artist: ")
    song_info(artist,song)
    print("Do you want to add more songs? : ")
    print("Type n to STOP: ")
    answer = input()
    

song_list()
#print(playlist)
```

When I run this I get TypeError: song_list() missing 1 required positional argument : 'playlist'

I even tried moving playlist[] under the functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple programming error.

Comment out the last call to song_palylist() which is outside the while loop.

```
def song_list(playlist):    
    for song in playlist:
        if song['song_title'] == True:
            print(song['song_title'] + ' by ' + song['song_artist'])

song_playlist(playlist)
```

Also as playlist is a global variable. You can just remove it from plyalist function as an argument & it will work.

When you are calling song_playlist() you need to pass a variable(list) as it as argument for the function.

So, Either remove playlist as an argumnent in function song_playlist() or whenever you call song_playlist function pass playlist as an argument.

Comment: Hello Rafiq,   How would I print out the song_list?  Would I do it in the while loop?   That's what I am looking to do.   When the customer is finished inputting data, I want it to print out a list of what they input.

Comment: I think you can just use song_list() function with playlist as argument.
Like:  `song_list(playlist)`

Also change print in song_list() functioon as:
`print(song['song_title'] + 'by' + song['song_artist'])`
As playlist is the actual list & song is a dictionary in playlist.